# Only want Date portion of DateTime

Tags: .net, datetime

```
<%= Model.STPData.InitialRateSettingDate.HasValue ? Model.STPData.InitialRateSettingDate.Value.ToString() : "" %>
```

This shows both the date and the timestamp. I tried using only the `.Date` property but it didn't work. How can I remove the time portion and display the date as a string only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DateTime has a `.ToShortDateString()` method

Comment: wow didn't even check for something like that. I'm a moron. =/